# function-try-block and noexcept

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++14, noexcept

For the following code

```
struct X
{
    int x;
    X() noexcept try : x(0)
    {
    } 
    catch(...)
    {
    }
};
```

Visual studio 14 CTP issues the warning

> warning C4297: 'X::X': function assumed not to throw an exception but
>   does
>
> note: __declspec(nothrow), throw(), noexcept(true), or noexcept was
>   specified on the function

Is this a misuse of `noexcept`? Or is it a bug in Microsoft compiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Or is it a bug in Microsoft compiler?

Not quite.

A so-called function-try-block like this cannot prevent that an exception will get outside. Consider that the object is never fully constructed since the constructor can't finish execution. The `catch`-block has to throw something else or the current exception will be rethrown ([except.handle]/15):

> The currently handled exception is rethrown if control reaches the end
>   of a handler of the *function-try-block* of a constructor or
>   destructor.

Therefore the compiler deduces that the constructor can indeed throw.

```
struct X
{
    int x;
    X() noexcept : x(0)
    {
        try
        {
            // Code that may actually throw
        }
        catch(...)
        {
        }
    } 
};
```

Should compile without a warning.